# Assume $\det A=-2,$ $C=(A^{T})^{2}BA^{3}B^{-1}A^{-3}$. Calculate $\det C.$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $A,B$ be $n\times n$ matrices. Assume $\det A=-2,$ $\det B\neq 0.$ $C=(A^{T})^{2}BA^{3}B^{-1}A^{-3}$. Calculate $\det C.$

I don't like to ask a question where I haven't at least made some headway, but with this I am not sure how to start, I see the $B^{-1}$ as problematic. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If $\det B=0$, $B$ has no inverse!

Comment: @Bernard The assumption is that $\det{B} \neq 0$.

Comment: Hint:  $\det(AB)=\det(A) \det(B),$  $\det (A^n) = (\det A)^n$  and $\det (A^T)=\det A$

Comment: Couldn't see that when I read it (perhaps a problem with my browser?)

Comment: Ok, Ill have a look at this now and see what I come up with. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One may recall that, if $\det A \neq 0$, then

> $$
> \det A{}^t=\det A, \qquad \det (A{}^{p})=(\det A)^p,\quad p=0,\pm 1,\pm2, \ldots.
> $$

and for any $B$,

> $$
> \det (\color{blue}{AB})=(\det A)(\det B)=(\det B)(\det A)=\det (\color{blue}{BA})
> $$

Thus here:
$$
\det C=\det ( (A^t)^2BA^3B^{-1}A^{-3})=(\det A)^{2+3-3}(\det B)^{1-1}=(\det A)^{2}=(-2)^2=4.
$$